# Calculating Wins/Losses for NBA Teams

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate

So I have a reporting table of player stats from each game this past NBA season in Snowflake. I'm trying to determine a team's Win/Loss Record and here are the relevant columns where team represents the team the player is currently on. (This sample data is abbreviated to 5 records for each game)

| GAME_ID | PLAYER | TEAM | HOME | HOME_FINAL | AWAY | AWAY_FINAL | GAME_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jalen Brunson | NYK | NYK | 112 | MIN | 106 | 2024-01-01T15:00:00.000000Z |
| 1 | Julius Randle | NYK | NYK | 112 | MIN | 106 | 2024-01-01T15:00:00.000000Z |
| 1 | Josh Hart | NYK | NYK | 112 | MIN | 106 | 2024-01-01T15:00:00.000000Z |
| 1 | Donte DiVincenzo | NYK | NYK | 112 | MIN | 106 | 2024-01-01T15:00:00.000000Z |
| 1 | OG Anunoby | NYK | NYK | 112 | MIN | 106 | 2024-01-01T15:00:00.000000Z |
| 2 | Jalen Brunson | NYK | NYK | 116 | CHI | 100 | 2024-01-03T20:30:00.000000Z |
| 2 | Julius Randle | NYK | NYK | 116 | CHI | 100 | 2024-01-03T20:30:00.000000Z |
| 2 | Josh Hart | NYK | NYK | 116 | CHI | 100 | 2024-01-03T20:30:00.000000Z |
| 2 | Donte DiVincenzo | NYK | NYK | 116 | CHI | 100 | 2024-01-03T20:30:00.000000Z |
| 2 | OG Anunoby | NYK | NYK | 116 | CHI | 100 | 2024-01-03T20:30:00.000000Z |

Given the final scores for the home team, away team; and an identifier for the home and away teams I want to find a team's Win/Loss record by month/season/etc. Seems simple enough, but I think with my current logic it's summing every player record in each game as a Win/Loss (so if the NYK lose and had 12 players play my logic picks this up as 12 losses for one game when I need it to pick that up as one loss for the entire game). I'm also not 100% confident that my case statements are set up correctly. What can I change to get the proper output?

```
SELECT 
    team,
    AWAY_WINS + HOME_WINS as WINS,
    AWAY_LOSSES + HOME_LOSSES as LOSS
FROM (
SELECT 
    game_id,
    team,
    SUM(CASE WHEN away = team AND away_final > home_final THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AWAY_WINS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN home = team AND away_final < home_final THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HOME_WINS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN away = team AND away_final < home_final THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AWAY_LOSSES,
    SUM(CASE WHEN home = team AND away_final > home_final THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HOME_LOSSES
FROM PLAYER_REPORTING_TABLE t1
WHERE MONTH(TO_DATE(t1.GAME_TIME)) = 1 AND YEAR(TO_DATE(t1.GAME_TIME)) = 2024 AND team = 'NYK' 
GROUP BY team, game_id
)
GROUP BY team, wins, loss;
```

Comment: If you are not sure if your calculations are correct, then take a small subset, calculate it manually, then compare it to your query

Comment: So, for game_id 1, is there another set of records for Minnesota?...and does it also have game_id 1 or does it have a different  game_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select team,
    sum(case when pts > opponent_pts then 1 else 0 end) as wins,
    sum(case when pts < opponent_pts then 1 else 0 end) as losses
from (
    select distinct game_id, team,
        case when home = team
            then home_final else away_final end as pts, 
        case when home = team
            then away_final else home_final end as opponent_pts
    from PLAYER_REPORTING_TABLE
    --where ...
) as scores
group by team;
```

That inner query will give one row per team per game. Even though you don't need it later, `game_id` in this result is important so you don't eliminate games against the same opponent that ended with the same score. It's easy to summarize after that.

https://dbfiddle.uk/7Zm38k-7

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! So I pretty much just needed to separate the logic in my case statements. Once we identify whether a team's final score was the home or away score in the inner query, then just like you said, summarizing total wins/losses in the outer query becomes very easy because we've already differentiated!

Comment: @BlackMagic, I think that bit with the scores helps to clean up the logic. But the `select distinct` is also important to prevent counting the game multiple times. From where you started, I think that second part was the critical step. Btw your original query could have been tweaked this way: `count(distinct CASE WHEN away = team AND away_final > home_final THEN game_id ELSE null END) AS AWAY_WINS`...

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1. You have more detail than you need; you have repeated team data at the player level.  That should immediately put you on alert to ask, what if they are inconsistent?
2. The scores have a level of indirection about home vs. away which makes determining 'W's & 'L's a bit complicated.

I would first summarize all the team data up to the team level, then count up W's & L's after.  I use the max() function here to resolve possible data inconsistencies.  It may not be the correct way to do it for the kind of inconsistency you may have.

```
Select team, winloss, count(*) as games
From (
    Select team, game_time, max(home) as home, max(away) as away
       ,max(home_final) as home_final, max(away_final) as away_final
       ,max(Case When team=home and home_score>away_score
                 or team<>home and away_score>team_score
            Then 'W' Else 'L' End) as winloss
    FROM PLAYER_REPORTING_TABLE 
    Group by team,game_time
)
Group By team, winloss
Order By team, winloss desc
```